# $ArgZ$ is continuous except Negative X axis.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I know how to show the function $ArgZ$ is not continuous on negative real axis. But I can not prove how it is continuous else where. 
 Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271117/continuity-of-arg-z and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624840/108128.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}
&=\frac{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}\\[12pt]
&=\tan(\theta/2)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(1)$, $\sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, and $\cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\arg(x+iy)
&=\theta\\
&=2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
which is continuous for all $\mathbb{C}$ away from the negative real axis (the negative real axis is precisely where $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x=0$).

Comment: This is parallel to the [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271693). The only difference being the branch of $\arg$ used. Here it is the branch from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and there it is the branch from $0$ to $2\pi$.